# Prove that $\lim_{R\to 0}\int_R^\infty 2n_0 (\frac{r_0}{r})^{\alpha} \frac{r\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{r^2-R^2}}$ converges when $a<1$

Tags: improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

[image]

This problem is from [Galaxies in the Universe: An Introduction, 2nd Edition](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511807237)

For the first question, it is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4791810)

But for the second question, it seems wierd that:

$$
\lim_{R\to 0}\Sigma(R) = \int_0^\infty 2n_0 (\frac{r_0}{r})^{\alpha} \mathrm{d}r = \int_0^b 2n_0 (\frac{r_0}{r})^{\alpha} \mathrm{d}r + \int_b^\infty 2n_0 (\frac{r_0}{r})^{\alpha} \mathrm{d}r
$$

**The first term is converged when $a<1$ but the second term is converged when $a>1$**

Maybe I should not use the $\int_0^\infty 2n_0 (\frac{r_0}{r})^{\alpha} \mathrm{d}r$ and get back to:

$$
\lim_{R\to 0}\int_R^\infty 2n_0 (\frac{r_0}{r})^{\alpha} \frac{r\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{r^2-R^2}}
$$